# Column Spacing/Padding

Tags: html, css, row

I am trying to get my column padding closer together however I have padding set to 0 and theres still a gab in between. I want to make it so the columns are close to eachother no matter what screen sizer and theres 2 items per row. Doesnt even show the words of second row

```
   <body>

   </body>
   <div class="pimg3">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="ptext">
                <h1><strong>HOW I WORK</strong></h1>
                <div class="column">
                    <i class="fas fa-search" style="color:#1d5ba0; padding: 10px"></i>
                    <h2>Research</h2>
                    <p>Understand the problem, empathize with the person. Explore the competitive landscape. 
                        Identify strategic opportunities. Define design goals/requirements.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <i class="fas fa-flask" style="color:#1d5ba0; padding: 10px"></i>
                    <h2>Design</h2>
                    <p>Combine effective interfaces, smart interactions, and consistent visual language into
                         a captivating design that resonates with the target audience.
                        </p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <i class="fas fa-code" style="color:#1d5ba0; padding: 10px"></i>
                    <h2>Build</h2>
                    <p>Map design to code. Smooth constraints. Solve edge cases. Move that button 3 pixels to the left. Fill 
                        the gap between functional and delightful.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <i class="fas fa-retweet" style="color:#1d5ba0; padding: 10px"></i>
                    <h2>Refine </h2>
                    <p>Test prototypes with real people against actual problems. Combine insights with gut intuition and experience. 
                        Iterate and improve in pursuit of perfection.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        
    </body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kdb4raLx/1/

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to your ptext seems that is a culprit

Comment: Thanks for that I know the cause but how should it be setup?